# overflow error in the program for performing 16bit addition

Tags: assembly, addition, x86-16, microprocessors, addressing-mode

```
.model small
.stack 200
.data
arr dw 1234h,4321h,1dup(?)
.code
start:
mov ax,@data
mov ds,ax
xor ax,ax
lea si,arr
mov ax,[si]
mov bx,[si+2]
add ax,bx
mov [si+4],ax
int 03h
end start
```

error is :

> (4)overflow! -cannot be evaluated: arr dw 1234h,4321h,1dup(?)

Comment: It would help if you tell us which assembler you are using.

Answer (score 1):

`1dup(?)` needs spaces: `1 dup (?)`.

Comment: And `1 dup` doesn't make any sense :)

Comment: @Jester: neither the rest of the code :-) . But this eliminates the error message.